# Adding data to Django

Tags: python, django, permissions, restriction

I'm working on an existing, fairly large, Django application. It has the `django.contrib.auth` app in `settings.py` so it already has `User` and `Group` models.

I'm trying to use the `Group` to restrict a list of users in two ways:

1. Hide a web page element (button) from users are in a new group
   "guides"
2. Prevent the same users from being able to invoke the API endpoint
   URL directly

I think I can do this by adding the new group "guides" to the Group model and then adding a list of users to that group.

My question is how to create the new group and add the list of users to that group in a way that can be moved to our Dev, State, and Prod environments, but only occur one time during deployment (CircleCI).

Comment: I think you can create a migration or maybe a command. Have you considered that?

Comment: If you need to create some initial data, you can generally use fixtures which load data from files (usually JSON) during migrations (or via management command); https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/initial-data/

Comment: Thanks for both responses. I was looking at adding a command to manage.py to do the work. In there I was thinking of doing a test to see if the "guides" group existed, and using that to either add the group (and the users), or not, as a way to leave this in place, but effectively have it do something only the first time it's run.